# Methods that only return arrays are very common. But, in the 'returns' argument, do I use memory or storage? and why?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, arrays, memory

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
    
contract MyContract{
        address[] public myAddresses;
    
        function getMyAddresses() public view returns(address[] [[memory? / storage?]]){
            return myAddresses;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to return an array or a string from a function, you need to specify "memory" in the returns statement. This is because the contract would need to store the returned data somewhere. Since storing in the "storage" needs gas, the location chosen is "memory".

For detailed description, you should refer to [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-which-to-use-in-local-functions-72b593c3703a) article.